# jQuery pass argument to $.get() callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using this piece of code to retrieve some JSONs from twitch:

```
for (var i = 0; i < streamList.length; i++) {
     $.get(baseURL + streamList[i], getStreamInfo, "json");
}
```

where getStreamInfo is the callback function. I would like to know if it is possible to pass the value of "i" to the callback function somehow, along with the JSON.

Comment: `$.get(...).done(getStreamInfo.bind(undefined, i));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
for (var i = 0; i < streamList.length; i++) {
    (function(index){
        $.get(baseURL + streamList[i], function(data){
            getStreamInfo(data, index);
        }, "json");
    })(i);     
}
```

Note: Modify your function `getStreamInfo` to accept `index`.

Read [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass the default parameter that receive the data of the ajax query and then add the `i` var.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < streamList.length; i++) {
     $.get(baseURL + streamList[i],
           function(data) { getStreamInfo(data, i) }, 
           "json");
 }
```

Note that you need to receive it in `getStreamInfo` function

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope... https://jsfiddle.net/gbf0fwqo/ - [Javascript infamous Loop issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue)

Answer (score 2):

You can add any variables you want to the anonymous object. Be sure those variables are not used by the `get` function.
For exemple, I added the variable `foo` to the anonymous object and used it with `this.foo` in the callback function :

```
for (var i = 0; i < streamList.length; i++) {
    $.get({
      url: baseURL + streamList[i],
      success: getStreamInfo,
      dataType: "json",
      foo:i
    });
} 

function getStreamInfo()
{
    var i = this.foo;
}
```